# Marginal notes overrun the paper even if only papersize is specified

Tags: margins, geometry

The following seemingly innocent MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  papersize={170mm,240mm},%
  verbose%
}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

leads to the following warning:

> Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
>        Add 3.44473pt and more to the right margin.

Note that, by contrast to the question [Warning message: "The marginal notes overrun the paper"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108213/18401), here margins are not specified.

How can that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the width for marginal notes, `geometry` uses the default 65pt with a default `\marginparsep` of 11pt.

Its heuristics lead to a text width of 338.5863pt, over a 483.69684pt page width, with equal margins at either side, so the margin width is 72.55527pt; since 65+11=76 is larger than the available margin, a warning is issued.

If you specify just the paper width, `geometry` sets the text width at 70% of the page width, see section 6.5 of the manual, bottom of page 13, case S(0,0). Indeed, 483.69684*0.7 = 338.587788, which agrees with the stated text width, up to the usual TeX rounding to scaled points.

If you specify `includemp`, you get

```
* \paperwidth=483.69684pt
* \paperheight=682.86613pt
* \textwidth=262.5863pt
* \textheight=478.0042pt
[...]
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
```

and no warning. But you see that the default values for `\marginparwidth` and `\marginparsep` are still used.